# Rewriting the multi-dimensional Dirac delta function

Tags: dirac-delta

Consider the $d$-dimensional delta function $\delta^{(d)}(x)\equiv\prod_{i=1}^d\delta(x^i)$. Since
$$
x^i=0,~\forall i\iff \sum_i(x^i)^2=0
$$
it should be possible to write
$$
\delta^{(d)}(x)=f(x)\delta(r)
$$
where $r=\sqrt{\sum_i(x^i)^2}$.

My question is what is $f(x)$? Is it $f(x)=\frac{1}{\Omega_{d}r^{d-1}}$? (where $\Omega_{d}$ is the $d$-dimensional solid angle)

Comment: Why not just integrate your proposed equality against a test function and try to solve for $f$? There's no need to guess

Comment: @kevinkayaks Ah very good. In that case I get $f(x)=\frac{1}{4\pi r^2}$